# Orthogonal complement of $Y = \{ x = (x_n) \in l^2: x_{2n} = 0, \, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let

$$ 
Y = \{ x = (x_n) \in l^2: x_{2n} = 0, \, n \in \mathbb{N}\}
$$

> If $x = (x_n) \in Y^{\perp}$ then $$ x_{2n + 1} = \langle x, e_{2n +
>  1} \rangle = 0, \, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

and thus
$$
Y^{\perp} = \{ x = (x_n) \in l^2: x_{2n + 1} = 0, \, n\in \mathbb{N} \}
$$

**Question:**

Can someone explain why the argument inside the rectangle is true?

Obviously, the sequences $(x_n)$ that give

$$
\langle x_n, y_n \rangle = 0, \, \forall (y_n) \in Y
$$
are those with $x_{2n +1} = 0$ (zero odd terms).

But what's the point made inside the rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with Hilbert space, remember that forall $Y\subset X$
$$Y^\perp =<Y>^\perp$$
where $<Y>$ denote the set of linear combinations of elements of $Y$. This means, in your case, that since 
$$\{e_{2n+1}\}_n^\perp=<\{e_{2n+1}\}_n>^\perp=Y^\perp$$
which is exactly as stated in the rectangle,
since $\{e_{2n+1}\}_n$ is a basis for $Y$

Answer (score 1):

The point made is that the sequence $e_{2n+1}$ with all vanishing terms except the $2n+1$-th one which is equal to one is belonging to $Y$. Hence for $x \in Y^\perp$, the inner product $\langle x, e_{2n+1} \rangle = x_{2n+1}$ is vanishing.